# How to stop closing of Kendo MultiColumnDropDown until done selecting items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo MultiColumnDropDown, that has 2 columns in it, one column is checkboxes, the other is just data.

Everytime I check a checkbox then the dropdown closes, I don't want that to happen until I close it myself and can't figure out how to stop the select event or to stop the dropdown from closing until I close it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  LoadMCDD(MCDDData());
});

function LoadMCDD(ds) {
  let a = ds[0].DropData;
  let arr = a.split('|');
  let obj = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    obj.push({
      DropData: arr[i]
    });
  }

  $('#MCDDForPrompt').empty();
  $('#MCDDForPrompt').kendoMultiColumnComboBox({
    placeholder: "Select...",
    dataTextField: "DropData",
    dataValueField: "DropData",
    height: 300,
    autoClose: false,
    columns: [{
        template: "<center><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' /></center>",
        width: "30px"
      },
      {
        field: "DropData",
        title: "Data",
        width: 200
      }
    ],
    dataSource: {
      data: obj,
    },
    change: function(e) {
      //console.log(e);
    },
    select: function(e) {
      //console.log(e);
    }
  });
}


function MCDDData() {
  let ds = [{
    Answer: "",
    DefaultAnswer: "",
    DropData: "Check 1|Check 2|Check 3|Check 4",
  }];

  return ds;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />

<div id="MCDDForPrompt" style="width:400px"></div>
```

Comment: A Kendo `MultiColumnComboBox` can have only one value, I suppose that's why it doesn't really make sense to prevent auto close. Kendo `MultiSelect` seems to be a better match for your requirement (it has the `autoClose` property you're trying to use).

Comment: @Métoule, I did take a look at the multiselect, but I don't like how it adds my selections to the textbox like that. I guess what I can do is just create something similar to the multicolumndropdown or maybe i'll take a look and see if the dropdownlist can use templates in it

Comment: You can customize every part of the `MultiSelect`, including what's displayed in the textbox via the `tagTemplate` property.

Comment: I'll take a look at that right now, thanks for the idea

Comment: "...but I don't like how it adds my selections to the textbox like that..."  *Q: What representation are you looking to see for multiple selections ?*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select: function(e) {
  e.sender.element.data('fromSelect', true);
},
close: function(e) {
  if (e.sender.element.data('fromSelect')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.sender.element.data('fromSelect', null);
  }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  LoadMCDD(MCDDData());
});

function LoadMCDD(ds) {
  let a = ds[0].DropData;
  let arr = a.split('|');
  let obj = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    obj.push({
      DropData: arr[i]
    });
  }

  $('#MCDDForPrompt').empty();
  $('#MCDDForPrompt').kendoMultiColumnComboBox({
    placeholder: "Select...",
    dataTextField: "DropData",
    dataValueField: "DropData",
    height: 300,
    autoClose: false,
    columns: [{
        template: "<center><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' /></center>",
        width: "30px"
      },
      {
        field: "DropData",
        title: "Data",
        width: 200
      }
    ],
    dataSource: {
      data: obj,
    },
    select: function(e) {
      e.sender.element.data('fromSelect', true);
    },
    close: function(e) {
      if (e.sender.element.data('fromSelect')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.sender.element.data('fromSelect', null);
      }
    }
  });
}


function MCDDData() {
  let ds = [{
    Answer: "",
    DefaultAnswer: "",
    DropData: "Check 1|Check 2|Check 3|Check 4",
  }];

  return ds;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />

<div id="MCDDForPrompt" style="width:400px"></div>
```